# Need to reload table with newly added row

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I have a table that is created dynamically using php do while loop.  The query is on the same php page as the do while loop... like so:

```
$id = $someID['some_id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM itable WHERE some_id = '$id'";
$result = @mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

print"
<div id='divID'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>h1</th>
      <th>h2</th>
    </tr>
";   
    do{print"
     <tr>
       <td>" . $info['column1'] . "</td>
       <td>" . $info['column2'] . "</td>
     </tr>
    ";}
    while($info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
    print"
  </table>
</div>
";
```

works fine... then I add a row to the table using jquery post method... and the record is updated in the database correctly.  My question is how to get the table to refresh with the newly added row?  I understand that I can use $('#divID').load$('page.php');  However the query that populates the table is on the same page as the table itself so I'm not sure what to do here.  Any Help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You do ned to use the load function but instead of loading whole page just load the table again. You would do something like the following,

On button click :

a) add the record to database

b) Fire a JQuery load request to load the table again. Table will be in a div and all you need to do is append your newly received data to the div.

Comment: How do I refer to the table div?  $('#divID').load('whatgoeshere?');

Comment: Pretty much. It will go something like this : $('#div').load(url);

Comment: Pretty much that is too vague to be of any help... thanks for the attempt.

Comment: I added the line : $('#div').load(url); Which is really what's all needed.